# Проблемы с созданием итератора

Tags: c++, c++11, итераторы, segmentation-fault

Выполняю вот [это задание](https://stepik.org/lesson/53378/step/14?unit=31453). Необходимо написать итератор на лист векторов. Вылетает

> Failed. Runtime error
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Прогнал тесты: похоже, что проблема в реализации операторов инкремента и декремента, но я не могу понять, что я упускаю.

Заранее спасибо.

**UPD Теперь тут правильный код**

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

template<class T>
class VectorList
{
private:
    using VectT = std::vector<T>;
    using ListT = std::list<VectT>;

    ListT data_;

public:
    using value_type = T;

    VectorList() = default;
    VectorList(VectorList const &) = default;
    VectorList(VectorList &&) = default;

    VectorList & operator=(VectorList &&) = default;
    VectorList & operator=(VectorList const &) = default;

    // метод, который будет использоваться для заполнения VectorList
    // гарантирует, что в списке не будет пустых массивов
    template<class It>
    void append(It p, It q); // определена снаружи
                              //{
                            // if (p != q)
                            // data_.push_back(VectT(p,q));
                            // }


    bool empty() const { return size() == 0; }

    // определите метод size
    size_t size() const
    {
        size_t ans = 0;
        for (auto &v : data_)
        {
            ans += v.size();
        }
        return ans;
    }

    // определите const_iterator
    struct const_iterator : std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, const T>
    {
        typename ListT::const_iterator ItL;
        typename VectT::const_iterator ItV;
        const ListT* ptr;

        const_iterator() = default;
        ~const_iterator() = default;
        const_iterator(const const_iterator& It) = default;
        const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator&) = default;
        const_iterator(const ListT* ptr_) :
            ItL(ptr_->cbegin()), ItV(ItL->cbegin()), ptr(ptr_){};

        const_iterator& in_end()
        {
            ItL = --(ptr->cend());
            ItV = ItL->cend();
            return *this;
        }

        const T& operator*() const { return *ItV; };

        const_iterator& operator++()
        {
            if (ItV == std::prev((*ItL).cend()))
            {
                ++ItL;
                if (ItL != ptr->cend()) {
                    ItV = ItL->cbegin();
                } else {++ItV; --ItL; }
            }
            else
            {
                ++ItV;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        const_iterator operator++(int)
        {
            auto tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }

        const_iterator& operator--()
        {
            if (ItV == (*ItL).cbegin())
            {
                if (ItL != ptr->cbegin())
                {
                    --ItL;
                    ItV = std::prev((*ItL).cend());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                --ItV;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        const_iterator operator--(int)
        {
            auto tmp = *this;
            --(*this);
            return tmp;
        }

        bool operator== (const const_iterator& right) const
        {
            return (ItL==right.ItL && ItV==right.ItV);
        }

        bool operator!= (const const_iterator& right) const
        {
            return !(ItL==right.ItL && ItV==right.ItV);
        }

        const T* operator->() const { return &(*ItV); }

    };

    // определите методы begin / end
    const_iterator begin() const 
    { 
        return !data_.empty() ? const_iterator(&data_) : const_iterator(); 
    }
    const_iterator end()   const 
    {
        if (!data_.empty())
        {
            return const_iterator(&data_).in_end();
        }
        return const_iterator();
    }

    // определите const_reverse_iterator
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

        // определите методы rbegin / rend
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const 
    { 
        return !data_.empty() ? const_reverse_iterator(end()) : const_reverse_iterator(); 
    }
    const_reverse_iterator rend()   const 
    { 
        return !data_.empty() ? const_reverse_iterator(begin()) : const_reverse_iterator();
    }


};
```

Comment: Так а что вы ожидаете получить от `std::prev((*ItL).end())` в ситуации, когда вектор `*itL` пуст? Также, что это за странные реализации `==` и `!=`? Почему вы сравниваете *данные* по итератору вместо сравнения *самих итераторов*?

Comment: Да, вы, пожалуй, правы. Сейчас поправлю, но вообще я пробовал оставлять условие, а в теле условия писать просто что-то другое. Система говорила, что все ок, только ++ и -- делают не то, что ожидается

Comment: Поправил код, все еще где-то ошибка

Comment: в инкременте/декременте после ++ItL, делайте проверку не равен ли после этой операции ItL пустому итератору + прочитайте последний пункт моего ответа

Comment: Наверно, идиотский вопрос, но я уже шестой час сижу. Что лучше вернуть, если мы не можем сделать ++ItL? Потому что сейчас SF уже не бросает (код в вопросе я через пару минут поправлю), но ругается на реализацию операторов (извините, я постфиксную форму хорошо потом сделаю)

Comment: Ошибки все те же, по сути. Если первый вектор в списке пуст, то после инициализации итератора первый же `++ItV;` приведет к неопределенному поведению. А что будет, если сам список пуст? Уже даже попытка инициализации итератора приведет к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: Вектор не может быть пустым (во всяком случае, так в условии написано, если я все правильно понял)

Comment: Если "вектор не может быть пустым", то почему тогда ваш метод `empty()` реализован таким странным образом - через вызов "тяжелой" функции `size()`? Почему бы просто не возвращать `data_.empty()`?

Comment: Этот метод был определен еще в условии задания, писал его не я, а преподаватель

Comment: Ну, видимо, ошибка все же была. В комментариях я уже написал, что Segmentation Fault больше не вылетает. Теперь тестер ругается на неправильную работу операторов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Операторы сравнения итераторов:

```
bool operator== (const const_iterator& it) const
    {
        return *ItV == *it;
    }
```

- сравнение данных по значениям вместо итераторов?
- ItV имеет тип vector::const_iterator, а it имеет тип ListVector::const_iterator
  Решение (аналогично для operator!=):

  bool operator== (const const_iterator& it) const
      {
          return ItV == it.ItV;
      }

2) Оператор инкремента (наверно и декремента, не смотрел):

- не хватает проверки для ItL != end перед разыменованием
- не хватает проверки для ItL != end после фактического инкремента (кстати тут и крылась ошибка)

3) По соглашению все постфиксные формы инкремента/декремента должны реализовываться через префиксную форму. Т.е. все постфиксные операции должны выглядеть следующим образом:

```
const_iterator operator++(int)
{
    auto tmp = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Наверно, идиотский вопрос, но я уже шестой час сижу. Что лучше делать, если мы не можем пойти вперед/назад? Потому что сейчас SF уже не бросает (код в ответе поправил), но ругается на реализацию операторов (извините, я постфиксную форму хорошо потом сделаю)

Comment: @ВладСивирин Если итератор еще действителен, но следующий/предыдущий будет уже неактивным тогда операция должна выполняться корректно и итератор должен принимать значение end. Но если изменяется уже неактивный итератор - тогда лучшим вариантом будет выбрасывание исключения

Comment: Все, спасибо огромное, после многих часов страданий все же получилось!